# SE Editor, please stop breaking my lists when I add new points to them

Tags: bug, markdown, editor

It's relatively simple. I have a numbered list, which has a Bulleted sublist on the first point... Then I want to add the next point (using <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd>) and, shoops my bulleted sublist got included to the toplist.

Sample (type the below):

```
1. List point one:
 * Sublist Point one
 * Sublist Point two
1. List point two:

1. List point one:  
 * Sublist Point one
 * Sublist Point two
1. List point two:
```

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd> while the cursor is on the end of the last line and you get:

```
1. List point one:
2. Sublist Point one
3. Sublist Point two
4. List point two:

5. List point one:
6. Sublist Point one
7. Sublist Point two
8. List point two:

9. List item
```

---

I really don't like that...

Comment: Do you mean `shift + enter`? I tried control-enter and it did nothing, shift + enter had the effect you describe.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett I am doing this automatically now. Yeah it's shift+enter...

Comment: It actually doesn't display the behaviour you're describing if you fully indent the sublist.

Comment: It should still be consistent with Markdown’s rendering, though.